# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : unknown error: a.tagName.toUpperCase is not a function with reactJS elements through Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, reactjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I have an issue that has stumped me, I have a method that finds and checks if all elements are on a page, part of that method checks if a page element is enabled.

```
if (Driver.Instance.FindElement(identifier).Enabled == false)
 {
    // do some stuff
 }
```

However, the If statement is failing with the following error:

```
StackTrace:at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Execute(String commandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.get_Enabled()
...
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : unknown error: a.tagName.toUpperCase is not a function
(Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

This method is constantly called and works with numerous other test cases under similar circumstances, without issue, however, when trying to interact with the following element I get the error shown above:

```
<div class="sc-gGBfsJ lhiRYE" span="5">
   <svg aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="times" class="svg-inline--fa fa-times fa-w-11 sc-jnlKLf dmaYnw" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 352 512" name="tag-create-modal__dismiss-cross">
  <path fill="currentColor" d="M242.72 256l100.07-100.07c12.28-12.28 12.28-32.19 0-44.48l-22.24-22.24c-12.28-12.28-32.19-12.28-44.48 0L176 189.28 75.93 89.21c-12.28-12.28-32.19-12.28-44.48 0L9.21 111.45c-12.28 12.28-12.28 32.19 0 44.48L109.28 256 9.21 356.07c-12.28 12.28-12.28 32.19 0 44.48l22.24 22.24c12.28 12.28 32.2 12.28 44.48 0L176 322.72l100.07 100.07c12.28 12.28 32.2 12.28 44.48 0l22.24-22.24c12.28-12.28 12.28-32.19 0-44.48L242.72 256z"></path>
   </svg>
   <div class="sc-hdPSEv kfkXT" id="CreateTagPropSheet__container" name="undefined__container">
  <div class="sc-nrwXf egtFZS">
     <div class="sc-fKGOjr bfXSai sc-ekkqgF dATqpE">
        <h3 class="sc-cpHetk bdaBtw sc-crNyjn fXZflb" id="propertySheet__heading--undefined" name="propertySheet__heading--undefined">Create Tag</h3>
     </div>
  </div>
  <form name="create-Tag__form">
     <div class="sc-nrwXf egtFZS">
        <div class="sc-fKGOjr bfXSai sc-ekkqgF dATqpE">
           <div class="sc-hycgNl KoKFR"><label class="sc-jvEmr jErbdW sc-iBmynh kxfLCa">Tag Name</label></div>
           <div class="sc-chAAoq GJbAH" id="propertySheet__select--tagNameContainer" name="tagNameContainer">
              <div class="sc-dTLGrV dLLsoX"><input class="sc-ivVeuv fMqabh" color="normal" id="propertySheet__select--tagName" name="tagName" type="text" autocomplete="on" value=""></div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="sc-nrwXf egtFZS">
        <div class="sc-fKGOjr bfXSai sc-ekkqgF dATqpE">
           <div class="sc-hycgNl KoKFR"><label class="sc-jvEmr jErbdW sc-iBmynh kxfLCa">System Level Tag</label></div>
           <div class="sc-chPdSV Ekqp" id="isSystemLevelCheckContainer" name="isSystemLevelTagContainer">
              <input class="sc-kgoBCf fZucFc" type="checkbox" id="isSystemLevelCheck" name="isSystemLevelTag">
              <div class="sc-kGXeez clAVjW"></div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="sc-nrwXf egtFZS">
        <div class="sc-fKGOjr bfXSai sc-ekkqgF dATqpE"><button class="sc-bhlBdH gEVPJV" id="propertySheet__button--create-tag__Button" name="create-tag__Button" color="success">Create Tag</button></div>
     </div>
  </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm wondering if it has something to do with the element itself, and the above code is a snippet for our website that is built using react, where these elements are conditionally rendered.

DOes anybody have any ideas on what is/would/could be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: whats the locator used? i.e. identifier?

Comment: So this method gets called a number of times, I usually pass a by to check for an element that would be interactive e.g name="tagName". I keep a private static library of a number of page elements I would be interested in - they follow this principle ---- private static By _Tag_Name_Text_Field = By.Name("tagName"); ----- these are just passed around between methods like so e.g. ------------ public static Boolean FindElement(By identifier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Element.tagName

As per [**`Element.tagName`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName) the `tagName` read-only property of the `Element` interface returns the tag name of the element on which it's called. For example, if the element is an `<img>`, its `tagName` property is `"IMG"` (for HTML documents; it may be cased differently for XML/XHTML documents).

- Syntax:

  ```
  elementName = Element.tagName;
  ```
- Value: A string indicating the element's tag name. This string's capitalization depends on the document type:

  - For DOM trees which represent HTML documents, the returned tag name is always in the canonical upper-case form. For example, `tagName` called on a `<div>` element returns `"DIV"`.
  - The tag names of elements in an XML DOM tree are returned in the same case in which they're written in the original XML file. If an XML document includes a tag "", then the tagName property's value is "SomeTag".

Further, as per [**`Document Object Model (Core) Level 1`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-745549614):

> Note that this is case-preserving in XML, as are all of the operations of the DOM. The HTML DOM returns the tagName of an HTML element in the canonical uppercase form, regardless of the case in the source HTML document.

### Solution

As you have mentioned *code is a snippet using react* so before checking for the element is **Enabled** induce *WebDriverWait* for the *visibility of* the desired element as follows:

```
if (Driver.Instance.FindElement(identifier).Enabled == false)
if (new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("element_xpath"))).Enabled == false)
 {
    // do some stuff
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation, it was very useful - However As I mentioned this is a snippet, and I have omitted that I check the element is on the page. Apologies for the poor clarity on my part. I had a bit of a play with it, and I have found that I was unable to use '.Enabled' or most another normal selenium extensions (e.g. '.Click' etc) on these elements... very strange...

Comment: In the end i was able to switch the code around a bit and use the 'GetAttribute("Disabled")' to find the value I required - it ended up looking like so: if (Driver.Instance.FindElement(identifier).GetAttribute("disabled") != null) - To get around the interaction issues I was having with the elements, I used the OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions class. although I still don't really understand why the original way didn't work..

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and after digging for a while I noticed that there was some other element on the same page which I wasn't even interacting with had attribute name="tagname". The moment I changed it to tagname2, I didn't have this error anymore and I was able to interact with the target element properly.

Surprisingly, I had this issue with Chrome 81.0.4044.20 not with 80.x

Comment: I don't have a great explanation, but this worked for me.  I had an input with name="tagName", and that effectively prevented selenium from being able to find this and other elements on the page.   I can only imagine that "tagName" is somehow an undocumented reserved keyword.  Thanks for posting this.  FWIW, I was using Chrome 96.0.4664.110.

Comment: Even if the document has element id="tagName". We hit the same issue.