# Selecting dropdownlist using Selenium javascript error: a.tagName.toUpperCase is not a function

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have been trying to select value from a C# Dropdownlist. Locator is written as `By.CssSelector("[id$=ddl_All_EntityType]")`

```
    public void selectDropdownValue(By locator, int timeout, IWebDriver driver, string optiontext)
    {
        clickWhenReady(locator, 60, driver);
        var dd = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(locator));
        dd.SelectByText(optiontext);
        dd.SelectByValue("10");
    }
```

I can see browser clicking on the dropdown, value being present there. But I am getting the error

> javascript error: a.tagName.toUpperCase is not a function
>     (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.120)

Comment: You need apostrophes around the id value `"[id$='ddl_All_EntityType']"`

Comment: Giving same error after that too. Actually the error is happening when I call dd.Select*, till then its all good.

Comment: What is your chrome driver version?

Comment: It is 78.0.3904.7000.

Comment: You have incompatibility. Either update chrome to 78 or download driver for version 77 https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads.

Comment: I downgraded driver to version 77, still same issue.

Comment: Is it using the new driver? you can see in the stack trace the driver info.

Comment: possible duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54019559/openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-a-tagname-touppercase-is-not)

Comment: hard to say whether that 'duplicate' has a valid answer... looks like it's referencing specs and provides a workaround... but the OP seems to indicate it was worked around in some other manner in the comment to that answer..

Comment: Guy - yes its using the correct driver, i.e. downgraded one.

Comment: is the page you're testing reactJs built @HardikShah?

Comment: No Brett, its ASP.NET Webform with C#.

Comment: do you have an input control named `tagName` in the page you're testing by chance? note a Won't Fix issue was raised on the Google bug board in earlier version of chromedriver.  stating "The only solution for now is to avoid using id or name 'tagName'." [link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=767)

Comment: Brett, no I dont have any such element with name as "tagName".

Answer (score 0):

It's a weird error, tagName should always be a string and the only way to get that error is if tagName is an object (not null or undefined). This may not be the best solution but you can make that error go away with:

```
Object.prototype.toUpperCase = () => 'N/A'
```

Comment: Where should I check this? I am getting error on                  dd.SelectByText(optiontext);
 line.

Comment: However you do driver.execute_script in c#, sorry I don't know the exact syntax.